# Is there a passive form of “to masturbate”?

Tags: verbs, verb-forms, passive-voice

First of all, I hope this question does not get banned due to inappropriate content. It that is the case, I’d be glad to know how I can reformulate the question in order to stay within the rules.

Now, as I got into a discussion about sex, I got curious about this one thing:

There is an active form for *to masturbate*, which of course is that very form (*I masturbate, you masturbate, he/she masturbates. . . .*).

But since there are passive forms for

- to shoot → to get shot
- to wash → to get washed
- to rob → to get robbed
- . . . .

what about

- to masturbate → to be masturbated?

It doesn’t actually matter if you use the word *masturbate*, *wank*, *fap*, or whatever words you know. What I mean is, I cannot remember ever having read or heard a passive form for *to masturbate*. But what do you call a “handjob” if you intend to use the word *masturbate*?

What would an author write, if he wanted to write something like:

> She went down with her hand and started. . . .

And again, if this should be inappropriate, please let me know if/how I reformulate this question to stay within the rules.

Comment: Good point. There are actually quite a few instances of [*she masturbated him*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22she+masturbated+him%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) in Google Books, but it sounds a bit weird to me. *"She tossed him off"* worked for me, but that corresponds to *"I tossed **myself** off"*, so it's not even a directly replaceable verb (people don't usually say *"I masturbated **myself**"*, presumably because the "reflexive" sense is implicit).

Comment: The problem here is to do with intransitive verbs, which do not have passive forms.  You also cannot say **I am listened, *it was happened, *she was lied.*  The first and the third can be fixed with the preposition *to*, but the results shall not be true passives of *to listen* and *to lie*.

Comment: But I can say _"I am listened to"_, _"It is rumoured"_, can't I? Is there a rule how to distingish intransitive verbs, anyway? Or is it like _"If it sounds strange, it's intransitive..."_?

Comment: This question should not be answered by anyone named 'FumbleFingers'...dot dot dot...

Comment: @Stacky You can say *I am listened to* because it is the passive of the transitive phrasal verb *to listen to*, not of *to listen*; there is no passive for *I listened*, only for *I listened to (something/someone)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, the form you're looking for is "to be masturbated".

(Grumble deleted; I grant it was offtopic.)

Answer (score -4):

Masturbating is by definition something you do to yourself, so no. When someone is a passive object of that action, you use a different word: to be fingered, to get a handjob, to be fondled...

Although some synonyms for masturbate are used in both contexts: people can jerk off and get jerked off

Comment: Hmm... ok. Strange though that _"to jerk off"_ can be used passively as _"she jerks him off"_, while _"to toss off"_ used passively as _"she tosses him off"_ sounds somehow strange to me.

Comment: No, the passive of "to jerk off" is "to be jerked off." You you are (in the above comment) talking about transitive usages, not passive constructions.

Comment: Worth noting that in 1974 the average (mans) weekly wage was only £40.

Comment: What @Frank said. I do quite like one of OED's citations for the earlier **mastupration** - 1723   Onania (ed. 8) 122,   *I would not be thought from hence that Mastupration is allowable, whilst the End is otherwise attainable.* And no - I'm sure that writer would not have been thinking of [*getting his end away*](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080726105642AAOLFOA) (not in so many words, anyway! :)

Comment: The very fact that the phrase _mutual masturbation_ gets nearly a million Google hits should really (inaccurate a measure as Google hit counts are) be enough to dispel the misapprehension that “masturbating is by definition something you do to yourself”.

Comment: @Janus: I accept the (undeniable) logic of what you say, but I think we can safely assume the earlier ***mastupration*** was exclusively used in the *unaccompanied [onanism](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onanism), self-gratification* sense. And that even today, at least *some* people (incl. OP and Simone here) still see it that way.

Comment: @Fumble Fingers As a teenager I knew some giggling French girls who used to ask you to count by saying *un plot; deux plot, trois plot....* etc. When you got to *onze plot* they would burst into fits of uncontrollable laughter. I think the point was that it sounded like *on se pelote* meaning 'I am stroking myself'. But it is interesting that these things are reflexive in French (*se masturber*) suggesting it is an act which is uniquely performed on oneself.

Comment: @WS2 More accurately, they are inherently _transitive_ in French, rather unlike in English where they're only rarely transitive. In the most common use case, the object is the same as the subject, and the verb is transitive; but there's nothing wrong with “Elle l’a masturbé” either.

Comment: -1 Masturbation is not only something you can do to yourself. `Removed OED definition as it is not allowed under my license agreement`